# Regarding the accuracy of the Siamese CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
# We have 2 inputs, 1 for each picture
left_input = Input(img_size)
right_input = Input(img_size)

# We will use 2 instances of 1 network for this task
convnet = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=img_size,input_tensor=None)
convnet.trainable=True
x=convnet.output
x=tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(320,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
preds = Dense(101, activation='sigmoid')(x) # Apply sigmoid
convnet = Model(inputs=convnet.input, outputs=preds)

# Connect each 'leg' of the network to each input
# Remember, they have the same weights
encoded_l = convnet(left_input)
encoded_r = convnet(right_input)


# Getting the L1 Distance between the 2 encodings
L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensor:K.abs(tensor[0] - tensor[1]))

# Add the distance function to the network
L1_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])

prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(L1_distance)
siamese_net = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input],outputs=prediction)

optimizer = Adam(lr, decay=2.5e-4)
#//TODO: get layerwise learning rates and momentum annealing scheme described in paperworking
siamese_net.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['accuracy'])

siamese_net.summary()
```

and the result of training is as follows

```
Epoch 1/10
126/126 [==============================] - 169s 1s/step - loss: 0.5683 - accuracy: 0.6840 - val_loss: 0.4644 - val_accuracy: 0.8044
Epoch 2/10
126/126 [==============================] - 163s 1s/step - loss: 0.2032 - accuracy: 0.9795 - val_loss: 0.2117 - val_accuracy: 0.9681
Epoch 3/10
126/126 [==============================] - 163s 1s/step - loss: 0.1110 - accuracy: 0.9925 - val_loss: 0.1448 - val_accuracy: 0.9840
Epoch 4/10
126/126 [==============================] - 164s 1s/step - loss: 0.0844 - accuracy: 0.9950 - val_loss: 0.1384 - val_accuracy: 0.9820
Epoch 5/10
126/126 [==============================] - 163s 1s/step - loss: 0.0634 - accuracy: 0.9990 - val_loss: 0.0829 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 6/10
126/126 [==============================] - 165s 1s/step - loss: 0.0526 - accuracy: 0.9995 - val_loss: 0.0729 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 7/10
126/126 [==============================] - 164s 1s/step - loss: 0.0465 - accuracy: 0.9995 - val_loss: 0.0641 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 8/10
126/126 [==============================] - 163s 1s/step - loss: 0.0463 - accuracy: 0.9985 - val_loss: 0.0595 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
```

The model is predicting with good accuracy, when i am comparing two dissimilar images. Further it is predicting really good with same class of images.
But when I am comparing Image1 with image1 itself, it is predicting that they are similar only with the probability of 0.5.
in other case if I compare image1 with image2, then it is predicting correctly with a probability of 0.8.(here image1 and image2 belongs to same class)

when I am comparing individual images, it is predicting correctly, I have tried different alternatives did not workout.
May I know what might be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The L1 distance between two equal vectors is always zero.

When you pass the same image, the encodings generated are equal (`encoded_l` is equal to `encoded_r`). Hence, the input to your final sigmoid layer is a zero vector.

And, `sigmoid(0) = 0.5`.

[image]

This is the reason providing identical inputs to your model gives `0.5` as the output.

Comment: What should I have to change in the code?
Because this was effecting my testing accuracy as well. When I have tried to test the model with test set, it is giving 50% of test accuracy. But when I am checking each and every individual image it works really good. Except,  with the described problem above.
May I know , how do I over come this?

Comment: Replace the L1 function with something else. For example use `Add()` or `Concatenate()` and retrain the model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer to my Question.
Would you mind, can you please describe in detail , about Add(), or Concatenate()?

Comment: And my questions is, I think it is the general way of defining the L1_distance function for Siamese CNN?

Comment: L1 or any well-defined distance functions are not a good choice for siamese networks. It's always better to let the model learn the comparison function. It's best if you use `Concatenate()([encoded_l, encoded_r])`

Comment: So, if I concatenate, how do I pass the single value to sigmoid function? I mean without calculating the absolute distance between two encoded vectors?

Comment: Even in your lambda layer, you pass a vector, not a single value. L1 is computed for every point in the two vectors.

Comment: Mr.Susmit Agarwal, the  Concatenate works really good. Now if i upload image1 with respect to image1, so the model is predicting that they are 99% similar.
But still in the test set I have got only 50% accuracy? do not know why again this problem

Comment: Did you change the weights in the test set to use the newly trained model?

Comment: I did not get you? what do you mean by weights in the testset?